# Why this error occurs in xcode for ionic4

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, ionic-framework, ionic4

I am trying to build the Ionic app in IOS. But when I start to build in XCODE, it gives me error like below.

```
Undefined symbols for architecture arm64:
"OBJC_CLASS$_GSDK_GTMLogger", referenced from:
    objc-class-ref in GoogleIPhoneUtilities(GIPReachability.o)
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture arm64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation).
```

I had searched for a day but all in vain. Anyone here with a solution for this? Thanks in Advance.

Comment: do you still have the same issue? i have given the answer below, is it helpful?

Answer (score 0):

Your ionic app not supporting the architecture of XCode, please try these steps to again build you app for ios.

```
ionic build --prod
sudo npm install -g ionic cordova
ionic integrations enable cordova --add
 ionic cordova prepare ios
```

Comment: Still same issue.

Comment: can you please show the tell me more detail? at which step you face the error? i have sent you 4  step? are these steps error free

Comment: Yes, these steps were error-free. But when I build again it gives same error.

Comment: Is it working okay with simulator? And what is the version of your xcode?

Comment: No it is not working.And Xcode version is 11.0. Have any other solution?

Comment: it should work on simulalor, may b there is another issue I can't help without seen the code